# The Error "EOF" is occurred in Minio console login

Tags: authentication, eof, minio

I am trying to [set secure access to stand-alone MinIO server](https://docs.min.io/docs/how-to-secure-access-to-minio-server-with-tls.html) using Docker container. I copied private.key and public.crt files to /root/.minio/certs. The ports is mapped like this: 9000:443 and 9001:9001.

When I access image uploaded MinIO through HTTPS, It is work well. But When I tried to login to MinIO web console, I got the simple error message: "EOF". [Here is the capture image of console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN75K.png)

It is the returned message from API https://{$my_domain}:9001/api/v1/login, full reponse is as follows.

```
{
  "code": 500,
  "detailedMessage": "EOF",
  "message": "invalid Login"
}
```

Any idea to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. The reason was, that I forgot to change the

MINIO_SERVER_URL=http...  to MINIO_SERVER_URL=https...

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found cause of the problem myself. I forgot to change SERVER URL in env_file, so it was remained localhost.

```
MINIO_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:9000
```